# No hyphen for a word

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I want to put pdflatex to not put a hyphen in a word went it comes to the end of the line.

I tried to put a `\-` in the beginning or the end of that word but it doesn't work.

For example if I put:`This is a very long sentence that needs two lines with thatshouldnot\- be hyphened` I will get:

> This is a very long sentence that needs two lines with thatshouldnot-
>   be hyphened

and if I do it this way: `This is a very long sentence that needs two lines with \-thatshouldnot be hyphened` I will get:

> This is a very long sentence that needs two lines with -
>   thatshouldnot be hyphened

I want 'thatshouldnot' to stay in one word and with no hyphen in the beginning or the end of the word.

Comment: Do you want to suppress hyphenation of (a) all words everywhere, (b) all words of that paragraph, (c) all occurences of `thatshouldnot`, or (d) only this one word `thatshouldnot` ?

Comment: @tohecz (c) all occurences of `thatshouldnot`

Comment: Is this similar to my question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100010/automatically-prevent-line-break-at-hyphen-of-specific-words-e-g-dual-self

Comment: @Jörg Yes, it is.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

if this word appears more than once in your document, and you never want it to be hyphenated, you can suppress hyphenation everywhere by putting this line in the preamble:

```
\hyphenation{thatshouldnot}
```

if it only occurs once, then david's answer using `\mbox` suffices.

**addendum:** 
A language that treats an apostrophe as a letter (such as Italian; see [Preventing hyphenation of a word with \hyphenation does not always work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678615)) and is processed with Xetex may not recognize an exception entered with `\hyphenation`.  In the cited case, there are two workarounds.  For the first, replace the ASCII apostrophe (U+0027) by the right single quotation mark (U+2019). `\mbox` should always work as a last resort.

Comment: it does not work for an acronym like `K-PLUS'

Comment: @Valerio -- can you give an example?  how is the acronym input/referenced?

Comment: as a simple text: "..if we consider K-PLUS then we would..."

Comment: that already contains a hyphen.  the only practical way to suppress a break in that case is to box it.  there is a "less practical" way, and that is to set `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`; since this will suppress breaks after *all* explicit hyphens, it has to be buried in a group along with the string on which it is supposed to act.

Comment: thanks. could you please tell me what to put in the preamble?

Comment: @Valerio -- to handle this in the preamble, you will have to make a command: `\newcommand{\KPLUS}{\mbox{K-PLUS}}`.  it would be better, usually, to deal with it in the main text: `if we consider \mbox{K-PLUS} then ...`

Comment: thanks! i've put `\newcommand{\KPLUS}{\mbox{K-PLUS}\ }` otherwise there is no space afterwards

Comment: @Valerio -- that will *always* put a space after "K-PLUS", even if it is followed by a period or comma.  the `xspace` package is meant for use in such situations (although it's overkill, and not recommended by some high-profile users); look for information by searching in this site.

Comment: @barbarabeeton why if we put in text `\mbox{K-PLUS}` it can be split across the line, whereas if we put in preamble with command (`\newcommand{\KPLUS}{\mbox{K-PLUS}}`) it won't be split ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă -- no, anything in an `\mbox` is by definition unsplittable.  if you did this: `\newcommand{\KPLUS}{K-PLUS}` without the box, it *would* be splittable.  the `\mbox` needs to be applied just at the point where a break at a hyphen is *not* wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think your addendum is misleading, it only applies to xetex and there (it turns out) you can use `’` rather than `'` in `\hyphenation`

Comment: Okay, if I update it with those modification, will you vet it?

Answer (score 178):

Put it in a box:

```
\mbox{thatshouldnot}
```

Comment: If I define `\newcommand{\tsn}{\mbox{thatshouldnot}}` and write "Testing the \tsn command.", there is no space after thatshouldnot. Why?

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti number 1 FAQ, the space is used to terminate the command, you can not write `the \tsncommand` so you need a space to end `\tsn` so use `\tsn\ command` to print a space. this is true of every tex command.

Comment: Thank you. Although it would be nice if I could simply use the `mbox`-ed command without needing to manually type `\ ` in the document body whenever I want a space. Is there a solution in which I create a command which automatically inserts `\ ` if the command is inside a sentence and does nothing when it is the last word of a sentence (followed by a full stop)? This would make the document body easier to read and type.

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti I wrote such a package, but... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\tsn}{\mbox{thatshouldnot}\xpspace}`

Comment: Alternatively, use `\tsn{}`.