# Latex hyphenation exception

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I have some problems with my document. I have one sentence with indentation. It is too long and it takes minimum two lines. And I have something like this:

```
Macierz rozproszenia idealnego, dopasowanego pierścienia hybrydowego ma po-
stać:
```

but I want something like this:

```
Macierz rozproszenia idealnego, dopasowanego pierścienia hybrydowego ma
postać:
```

Is it possible to do it automatically or must I do it by myself? Or is it correct?

Comment: very similar to this question: [No hyphen for a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67571/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just wrap the word in a box:

```
Macierz rozproszenia idealnego, dopasowanego pierścienia hybrydowego ma \mbox{postać:}
```

If you never want the word hyphenated, you can declare a new hyphenation with:

```
\hyphenation{postać}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that \hyphenation will only accept words that consists only of characters in the current font encoding. I.e.,  ć has to be a single character in the font not a "c" with an accent above. In other words the above would require \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} or something similar, in LaTeX's default encoding OT1 this would fail with "! Improper \hyphenation will be flushed.".