# Automatically prevent line-break at hyphen of specific words (e.g. "dual-self")

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, hyphenation

Usually questions about hyphenation and line-breaks are concerned about how to allow hyphenation when a word already contains a hyphen. That's not what I'm after:

I would like to prevent the word "dual-self" to be broken across lines. I know that I can to that manually with `dual\=/self`, but is there a way to achieve this automatically? Ideally something in the preamble equivalent to `\hyphenation{...}` where I can specify the words that should not be broken.

Comment: Have you tried `\hyphenation{...}` but not giving points at which to hyphenate? That's what I'd do first...

Comment: @vonbrand How would that look like? Given that the word is "dual-self", writing `\hyphenation{dual-self}` or `dualself` would not make much sense.

Comment: Perhaps `\hyphenation{self\-dual}` works? (Wild guess)

Comment: do you want this only for special words? because `\exhyphenpenalty10000` will prohibit hyphenation at all explicit hyphens like here in the word `dual-self`.

Comment: @user700902 Would you like to make an answer from your comment?

Comment: @user700902 Although originally I was after a solution that works for specific words, I believe `\exhyphenpenalty10000` is fine for my purposes as well. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(CW from comments)

By setting

```
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

in the document preamble, no explicit hyphen will be used for a line break.