# No hyphenation for author within a paragraph

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

I am using biblatex and biber. Inside the text I use the commands `citet`, `parencites` or `cite`with author-year. I would like to prevent that the last name sometimes gets hyphenated in the text.

Is there a command for bibsetup? Unfortunately I could not find something in the manual. Or is there any other possibility so that the last name stays as one part.

Thank you...
Christian

Comment: the answer to this question might help: [No hyphen for a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/579)

Comment: Then the entire entry is inside the box, but in my case the name must not be hyphenated but could deb separated from the year. Any further ideas?

Comment: i believe that with some bibliography systems, the space between author and year in citations is set up to not break.  to be able to provide a more specific answer, we will need an actual (minimal) example to experiment with.

Comment: Crosspost to the german [mrunix](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?76615-biblatex-Trennung-von-Namen-im-Flei%DFtextes&p=359836#post359836).

Comment: To prevent name-year separation you can redefine `\nameyeardelim` to be `~`.

Comment: @ulrikefischer gave the answer in the german forum. Add `\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}` to the preamble of the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Since you seem to have answered the question in the crosspost, would you be so kind an provide an answer here as well, so the question can be marked as solved?

Comment: @Johannes_B Maybe you can make that a CW answer until Ulrike comes along and adds an answer herself.

Comment: @moewe done so :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) gave the answer in the german forum the [question was crossposted](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?76615-biblatex-Trennung-von-Namen-im-Flei%DFtextes&p=359881&viewfull=1#post359881): `\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}`

[image: trinixBiblatexHyphenation]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bruchmueller2001,
Author = {Bruchm{\"u}ller, H.-G. and Haug, A.},
Note = {Schriftenreihe report -- Band 40},
Publisher = {Leuchtturm-Verlag},
Title = {Labordidaktik f{\"u}r Hochschulen -- Eine Einf{\"u}hrung zum Praxisorientierten Projekt-Labor},
Year = {2001}}

@book{DiBerardinis2013,
Author = {{DiBerardinis}, L. J. and Baum, J. S. and First, M. W. and Gatwood, G. T. and Seth, A. K.},
Publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
Subtitle = {health, safety, and environmental considerations},
Title = {Guidelines for laboratory design},
Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,%
backend=biber,%
maxcitenames=2,%
maxitems=999,%
language=ngerman,
maxbibnames=99,%
natbib
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\setlength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\usepackage{showframe}
\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}
\begin{document}
test word~\cite[vgl.][]{Bruchmueller2001}.\par
test word~\citet{Bruchmueller2001}.\par
test word~\parencites{Bruchmueller2001}.\par
test word~\cite[vgl.][]{DiBerardinis2013}.\par
test word~\citet{DiBerardinis2013}.\par
test word~\parencites{DiBerardinis2013}.\par
\end{document}
```