# Proper noun and prohibition of hyphen at the end of line

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I simply use irregular hyphen to supress `Overfull \hbox`. It's not beautiful and sometimes I even have to break syllables apart e.g. imm-ediately to avoid the hful box for the hyphen itself instead of imme-diately. But this time an author's name appears at this place. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You could encase the paragraph in a `sloppypar` environment to avoid the overfull `\hbox`, if you do not feel like hyphenating the author's name.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I did as you said but surprisingly received a hyphen after the second o in Chodorow.

Comment: To prevent unintended hyphenation, you can use `\mbox{Chodorow}` and, being in a box, it will not be broken apart.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I encased it in `sloppypar` environment  and used a tilde as following `Nancy~\mbox{Chodorow}. The entire above phrase in the image was moved to the next line. Thank you.

Comment: Great!  Since you also wanted `Nancy` to remain unbroken from the last name you could, for future reference, just have done `\mbox{Nancy Chodorow}`.

Comment: another way of globally avoiding a hyphen in "Chodorow" is to put the line `\hyphenation{Chodorow}` in your preamble.  (the tilde between `Nancy` and `Chodorow` would still have the same effect, but you wouldn't need the `\mbox`.)

Comment: Off-topic but I would not abuse hyphenation in order to avoid bad boxes. Distorting the rhythm of the language is worse, in my opinion, than breaking a particular set of typographic rules which are, after all, arbitrary up to a point. That is, when a box becomes bad or good is presumably a fuzzy issue and any rule sharpens this in a way that the typographic reality inevitably fails to fully support. Hyphenation patterns, on the other hand, are not generally arbitrary and abusive hyphens will be much more distracting to readers because clearly wrong.

Comment: @cfr I didn't know that hyphenation patterns do not break the syllable structure apart but even not knowing that is not a good excuse to do that. I really enjoyed your comment(specially "Distorting the rhythm of the language is worse"). By the way how do know hyphenation patterns follow this rule?

Comment: this might be considered a duplicate: [No hyphen for a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/579)

Comment: Hyphenation patterns are intended to break words at 'natural points' so that the points at which words are broken read naturally. Generally, this is going to mean not breaking words in the middle of syllables because this is not usually going to seem at all natural to speakers of the language. Note that the same word may be broken at different points in different varieties of the same language because, presumably, the patterns reflect different pronunciation patterns. (But I don't know much about it. You should ask @barbarabeeton or a linguist.)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I wouldn’t recommend to type `\mbox{Nancy Chodorow}`: you are certainly aware of the fact that the space inside the `\mbox` doesn’t stretch or shrink like the other spaces in the paragraph, and I deem this unacceptable, at least in a paragraph typeset by TeX!  One could use `\mbox{Nancy}~\mbox{Chodorow}`, rather.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I am aware that in the `\mbox`, the space will not stretch.  I agree that, if that is typographically unacceptable to the OP, your suggestion will provide the correct alternative.