# Preventing text from spreading over two lines in LaTeX

Tags: line-breaking, text

I have margins which I have to oblige by and also notes telling me that if I insert this tilde ˜ in front of each word it will stay on a line without getting broken. I have done this but this has not worked with

```
Lettre d'\'{E}tienne Pascal et Roberval ˜\`{a} ˜Fermat.
```

Fermat breaks onto the second line reading Fer-......mat.I tried with a standard ~ too. Any suggestions on how to prevent this break?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tilde symbols can be used to prevent line breaks between words, for example

```
Don't~break~this.
```

To prevent a word from being split up and hyphenated, you can use a box:

```
\mbox{Fermat}
```

Answer (score 1):

the flaw in your example is that you have left a regular typed space before the tilde.  that will always allow a line break, while usually doubling the width of the space.  tildes used in this manner should be the only "space" present.

however, avoiding a line break at a space in this manner won't prevent hyphenation,
if hyphenation would yield a paragraph with more uniform spacing.
some suggestions for avoiding hyphenation are given here:
[No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571)