# How to print lines of text without breaking the word within textwidth

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

How do I print the word VOLUNTEER in a single line without breaking,

Here is my MWE

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
 \documentclass[16pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}              %class
 \usepackage[landscape,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} %for layout
 \usepackage{setspace} % for spacing between lines
 \usepackage{graphicx}         %for including images
 \usepackage{eso-pic}     %package for including background image
 \usepackage{color,tikz}
 \usepackage{wallpaper}
 \usepackage{ulem}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{calligra}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{niceframe}
 \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{catechis} % Package for scripture
 \usepackage{ifthen}
 \newboolean{long}
 \usepackage{transparent,xstring}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{19,28,59}

 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}  
 \definecolor{a}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}

 \definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
 \def\signature#1#2{\parbox[b]{1in}{\smash{#1}\vskip12pt}
 \hfill \parbox[t]{2.8in}{\shortstack{\vrule width 2.8in height 0.4pt\\\small#2}}}
 \def\sigskip{\vskip0.4in plus 0.1in}
         \def\beginskip{\vskip0.5875in plus 0.1in}





 \input Elzevier.fd
 \newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}}

 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \newfontfamily{\lucida}{Lucida Calligraphy}
 \newfontfamily{\newroman}{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily{\maiandra}{Maiandra GD}
 \newfontfamily{\aafia}{Zengo}


 \newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=8pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
 \definecolor{brinjal}{RGB}{116,1,113}
  \begin{document}
 % \pagecolor{blue!10}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}


 \pagestyle{plain}


 \vspace*{-26mm}


  \noindent

 \hspace*{0cm}\begin{minipage}[c]{10.0in}
 {\centering
 {
 \vspace*{0.2cm}
 \newroman\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\bfseries\color{white} ~~~~$\textbf{44}^{\textbf{\textrm{th}}}$ National Workshop on ABCD/DBCE \& FGDAER\\ 

     }}

 \end{minipage}

 \hspace*{-0.5cm}\begin{minipage}[l]{1.5in}
 \vspace*{0.6cm}
 \vspace*{-0.7cm}\hspace*{-10.4mm}\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{example-image-a}

 \end{minipage}
  \hfill 

 \vspace*{2.3cm} 
 \hspace*{0.0cm}\begin{minipage}[l]{2cm}

  \end{minipage}

 \hspace*{1.3cm}\begin{minipage}{21.7cm}
 \begin{center}\vspace*{0.3cm}

 \end{center}
 \end{minipage} \hfill~~~
 \begin{minipage}[r]{0.9in}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.east)+(-5.0cm,5.6cm)$){\includegraphics[width=1.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}};  %here include right side image
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill

 \vspace{15mm}

 \hspace*{-0.2cm}\begin{minipage}[l]{25.0cm}

 {\doublespacing
 \lucida\noindent{This is to certify that~Mr./Ms./Dr./Prof. {{\textit{\color{red}\large\textbf{Biki Teron}}}}~~ has worked as \MakeUppercase{volunteer}~ in the ~\textbf{$\textit{34}^{\textrm{\textit{th}}}$ National Workshop on ABCD/EFGH \& Gahbsdfraew Devices} during 29 - 30 July, 2018 held at Abcdsa for Abcdtechnology, Dfghdj Institute of Technology Aghsdfar, Aaadk, Ppsdp.

 }}

 \end{minipage}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\mbox{\MakeUppercase{volunteer}}`

Comment: probable duplicate: [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571).  also, for this text, i'd be inclined to place it in a `center` environment since otherwise the spacing will be annoyingly uneven.  (i'd choose `center` rather than `raggedright` since i think this looks better for such a formal document.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent hyphenation of a specific word, wrap it in a `\mbox{}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[l]{13cm}
    This is to certify that~Mr./Ms./Dr./Prof. Biki Teron has worked as \mbox{\MakeUppercase{volunteer}} in the \textbf{$\textit{34}^{\textrm{\textit{th}}}$ National Workshop on ABCD/EFGH \& Gahbsdfraew Devices} during 29 - 30 July, 2018 held at Abcdsa for Abcdtechnology, Dfghdj Institute of Technology Aghsdfar, Aaadk, Ppsdp.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```