# newline begins with dash

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\hyphenation{ENCODE}
\begin{document}

All data used for this study are analysed with a different release of ENCODE \textendash\ the collection of software that is used in simulation and reconstruction.

\end{document}
```

In the output a new line is started with a dash which seems awkward:

[image]

Using `~` to control the line break:

`release of ENCODE~\textendash\ the collection`

causes also some awkwardness - hyphenation of "ENCODE":

[image]

Finally I can prevent the hyphenation of "ENCODE" by uncommenting the line `\hyphenation{ENCODE}` to obtain the pleasing output:

[image]

Can all this ceremony be automated?

Comment: Just out of curiousity: why don't you use `--` for en-dashes?

Comment: @JouleV, habit of mine

Comment: Considering [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/156344), I think there is only one another solution: using `\mbox{}`, but I don't consider it as an improvement.

Comment: You can define a variant for \textendash which doesn't break before, but beside this what other automatism do you expect to work?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I would like Latex to consider the output at the third attempt as the normal one.

Comment: Sure, but how should latex know that you don't want ENCODE to hyphenate unless you tell it with \hyphenation?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I see. Then never beginning a line with a dash would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress hyphenation with a box and linebreaking with a penalty:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\zz{\mbox{}~\textendash\ }
\begin{document}

All data used for this study are analysed with a different release of ENCODE\zz
the collection of software that is used in simulation and reconstruction.

\end{document}
```

The line is 2pt over full in this case.